Was the Russian Olympic Shooting Team 12 days late for the 1908 Summer Olympics due to a calendar mixup?
According to an article in Sports Illustrated, referred to by a reddit post, an article about programmer falsehoods, and elsewhere, the Russian Shooting team arrived 12 days late for the 1908 Summer Olympics due to a calendar mixup:

On July 11, 1908, the U.S. edged out Great Britain to take gold in the event. The Russians don’t appear on the standings and were non-competitive. Not because they weren’t any good, but rather because they weren’t present. While they arrived to town a few days before July 11, they did so according to the wrong calendar. Unlike the other teams, the Russian shooters arrived on the Julian date, which was twelve days after the Gregorian one. The event was long finished.

I cannot view the linked source in Google Books.  An article in Russia Beyond appears skeptical about the claim:

Nevertheless, all of the above are 21st-century publications, with no reference to the official sources, which never mentioned the Russian delegation being late. For instance, the Official Report of the Olympic Games of 1908, while describing the shooting competition of July 11, doesn’t include Russia. The national team surely didn’t participate, but was it even supposed to? Also, Italy and Australia are marked as absent, but Russia is not mentioned at all.
Honestly, it’s hard to believe that no member of the Russian delegation cared to check in with the calendar. Russia had been living next to Gregorian-calendar Europe for two centuries and was used to the two-week difference. The problem is that Russia didn’t have any official “delegation” at all. Back then, we didn’t care about the Olympics enough to even have an Olympic committee.

Wikipedia mentions the claim, but without contemporary sources:

Some sources claim that the Russian shooting team was 13 days late to the Olympics due to the Russian Empire still using the Julian calendar as opposed to the rest of Europe, which used the Gregorian system.

If true, I would expect at least some references in contemporary articles.  Are there any contemporary sources that can shed light on this claim, or do sources referring to this incident only appear much later, and is this incident more fiction than fact?

"Russia had been living next to Gregorian-calendar Europe for two centuries and was used to the two-week difference." The metric system has been around for about two centuries, and yet.

There is most likely nobody alive anymore, but there were some Russians born on Feb 29th 1900. In the western world 1900 was no leap year. Also Julian vs. Gregorian calendar.

@gnasher729 I was wondering why some sources claimed 12 days and others claimed 13 days, but decided to skip that aspect for the main interest being "did this happen at all".

@gerrit The Julian calendar only has the “four year” rule for leap years, so the difference increased by a day in 1900, and again in 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500. So a careless lookup in a table might give the wrong result.

To be fair, late for the opening ceremony is not the same as missing the games.

@gerrit says "I was wondering why some sources claimed 12 days and others claimed 13 days".  The offset changed from 12 to 13 on 1900-02-29, which was only 8 years earlier, so I expect that many people still thought it was 12, as that is what they had grown up knowing (just as many of us still instinctively think there are 9 planets, 18 years later).

@RayButterworth Yes, gnasher729 explained that, but it's a bit tangential to the question.

@JiminyCricket. According to Wikipedia, the 1908 games were spread over 187 days, so presumably athletes only came to the events relevant to them.
